# Triggers and Tables with SQL and NodeJs

Tags: sql-server, mysql, stored-procedures, trigger

Hi I 've a application runnning with nodejs and SQL server, What I need is that every time I Insert a record into the **ChargesTable** I need to check, how may charges does my user have made, and every 5 charges Insert data into an other table **BadgesTable**, i also need to do this every 10,15,20,50,100 charges. My question is if I can do this with a **Trigger** and how it would be, or should i use a **Storage Procedure**?

Comment: Trigger is enough. After Insert.

Comment: Can I use a Select and a if else sentence? , could u post a example ?

Comment: `SELECT` - yes, of course. `IF` - not needed, `WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM ...) IN (5,10,15,20,50,100)` is enough.

Comment: could you please write down the query I'm new into triggers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would probably be best implemented through the use of a trigger, and a separate table to keep track of charges, something like this.

First, create the separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE User_ChargeCount (
    userID bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    chargeCount int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
    )
```

Now, create a trigger on the Users table to automatically add a row each time a new user is added:

```
CREATE TRIGGER NewUser
ON Users 
AFTER INSERT AS
    INSERT INTO User_ChargeCount (userId)
    SELECT userID
    FROM inserted
```

If you already have users in the table, add their records also:

```
INSERT INTO User_ChargeCount (userId)
SELECT u.userID
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN User_ChargeCount uc
    ON u.userID = uc.userID
WHERE uc.userID IS NULL
```

Finally, add the trigger on your Charges table to log the new additions:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UserCharges_Insert
On UserCharges
AFTER INSERT AS
    UPDATE User_ChargeCount
    SET chargeCount += ct
    FROM User_ChargeCount u
    INNER JOIN (
        Select userId, 
            Count(*) as ct
        FROM inserted
        GROUP BY userId
        ) i
        ON i.userId = u.userID
```

At this point, if you need to retroactively populate the count, create the code to do that.

Finally, you will want to automate the reactions to the addition of a charge through a trigger on the User_ChargeCount table, like this. First, have a table containing the Charge count thresholds and the related Badge information:

```
CREATE TABLE UserChargeThresholds (
    ChargeCount int not null PRIMARY KEY,
    BadgeID int not null
    )
```

Then add your trigger for finding the badges that are needed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UserChargeThresholdCheck
ON User_ChargeCount
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    WITH CCCheck as (
        SELECT i.UserId,
            (Select MAX(ChargeCount)
             FROM UserChargeThresholds t
             WHERE t.ChargeCount <= i.chargeCount
             ) as NewCC,
            (Select MAX(ChargeCount)
             FROM UserChargeThresholds t
             WHERE t.ChargeCount <= d.chargeCount
             ) as OldCC
             FROM inserted i
             INNER JOIN deleted d
                ON i.userID = d.userID
        )
    INSERT INTO User_Badges
    SELECT userId,
        uct.BadgeID,
        GetDate() -- assumes a Date Badge Awarded field exists
    FROM CCCheck
    INNER JOIN UserChargeThresholds uct
        ON NewCC = uct.ChargeCount
    WHERE NewCC > OldCC
END
```

Now, all of the normal updates are automated. You will have to decide how you want to handle reversed charges, deleted charges, zero-charge rows, etc.